# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable 'for i'

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np

addon = ['DeviceProtection','OnlineBackup', 'OnlineSecurity', 'StreamingMovies', 'StreamingTV', 'TechSupport']

gender_addon = ['Gender'] + addon
addon_data = df_churn.loc[:, gender_addon]
gender = addon_data.groupby(['Gender']).agg('count')

result_female = ['Female']
result_male = ['Male']

for i in range (6):
    group = df_churn.groupby(['Gender',     gender_addon[i+1]]).agg({gender_addon[i+1]:'count'})
    female = int(group.iloc[2])/gender.iloc[0,i]
    male = int(group.iloc[6])/gender.iloc[1,i]

    result_female.append(female)
    result_male.append(male)

data = [result_female, result_male]
result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=gender_addon)
```

I think the code should be right but it says

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        13 
>        14 #calculate the percentages
>   ---> 15 for i in range (6):
>        16     group = df_churn.groupby(['Gender', gender_addon[i+1]]).agg({gender_addon[i+1]:'count'})
>        17     female = int(group.iloc[2])/gender.iloc[0,i]
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

I'm a beginner of python so really need help